# Content in div overlapping rounded corners.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to get rounded corners on a table element. Ideally, I would like the rounded corners to show on IE 7-10, Chrome, and Firefox. To do that, I am using [JQuery Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/). The problem I am facing is that when I apply the default rounded corner effect to the div that surrounds my table, the table overlaps the borders/corners.

Here a screenshot:
[image: border]

Why is table going outside of my div?

Comment: Do't try to force a browser to do things it doesn't support, things like this happen.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I don't see your point. You are saying that if the layout is ugly just leave that way because it's a browser issue? Are you saying that browsers don't support round corners?

Comment: No, don't leave it that way. If a certain browser doesn't support rounded corners, why should you bother to try to force it to? If it does, great! But it's wasted effort and often an uphill battle to try to get older browsers to do these newfangled things.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, Just to let you know, that screen shot was taken in the latest version of chrome. GionaF's answer fixed that for chrome but there is one minor issue with IE 7. There is no line around the border.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks I see. As Justing says, the question was applicable to all browsers, not just old browsers.

Comment: Aha, well I'm pretty sure you can't apply a border radius to a table..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Tables don't accept border-radius as a property.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/zBE6H/

What you can do is wrap it in a div and give that border radius, while removing the border of the table (or giving the border the same color as the div's background.)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/zBE6H/1/